# Execute less after changes

Tags: magento2, less-compilation

I am pretty new to Magento2 and my question may sound banana to most of you.
I would like to know how can I compile my less file.

> app/design/frontend/my_theme/web/css/source/_layout.less

thank you so much in advance

Comment: Do you mean deploy less file changes ?

Comment: yes, after changed I don't see my result, so I need to compile (deploy) to css file

Comment: **Kindly refer below link:** 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g8GvpDb3BBc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove **var** and **pub/static** folder and deploy static content again as per below commands.

```
rm -rf var/ pub/static/
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
chmod -R 777 var/ pub/static/
```

Comment: thank you , that's exactly what I needed. I may add to check the permissions of var and pub/static folders after the deployment. In my case they turned into not 770

Comment: You are welcome. I updated answer to add permission. Glad to know that it helped you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` from your project root folder.

You might have to remove contents of `pub/static` or to be more granular affected files by your changes.

Source: The official docs
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-static-view.html

Also if you want `GRUNT` to watch your changes see this
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html

In development environment you can also created symlinks as stated here
http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-less-sass.html

Also you should take into consideration the possibility that your logic for adding the `less` file is faulty. Here are the official docs for adding style custom changes

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-guide/css_quick_guide_approach.html

Comment: the command didn't work for me. I run it with normal and root user, flushed and refreshed the caches. nothing work. the changes are in the less file but I see the old css in styles-l.css

Comment: Please consider line added after edit "You might have to remove contents of pub/static or to be more granular affected files by your changes" this should be done before executing static-content:deploy

Comment: @bourax don't mention it